# NULL Empty Item in Bound ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

How can I have an empty item in the bound `ComboBox` which uses `NULL` as the value for an Insert or Update?

With the code below, I can manually add the additional row.  The column `inspector_id` is the primary key of an FK relationship.  I have to set `inspector_id = -1`, since C# does not allow an `int` to be `null`.  However, the insert (or update) fails since there is no `inspector_id: -1` in the database.

```
private void ItemInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'someDBDataSet.inspector' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.inspectorTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = false;
    someDBDataSet.inspectorRow newRow = this.someDBDataSet.inspector.NewinspectorRow();
    newRow.inspector_id = -1; // Since an int in C# cannot be null
    newRow.fullName = "(none)";
    newRow.employeeCode = "";
    this.someDBDataSet.inspector.AddinspectorRow(newRow);

    this.inspectorTableAdapter.Fill(this.someDBDataSet.inspector);
    //this.inspectorTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = false;
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'someDBDataSet.item' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.itemTableAdapter.Fill(this.someDBDataSet.item);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Eureka!** Bind to a view, not table.

Bind `inspector_idComboBox` to a new SQL Server view of the inspector table.

```
SELECT NULL as inspector_id, '(none)' as fullName, '' as employeeCode
UNION
SELECT inspector_id, fullName, employeeCode
FROM dbo.inspector
```

**Pros:**

1. The `(none)` item is in the `ComboBox`
2. The `SelectedItem` and text persists when selecting the item.
3. The SQL view allows a NULL value for `inspector_id`
4. No workarounds are needed in the application code.  Just fill the `DataSet` from the view.
5. Allows more flexibility as the relationship is not bound.

... brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

After trying various approaches, I initially decided on the following:

```
private void ItemInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.inspectorTableAdapter.Fill(this.someDBDataSet.inspector);
    this.itemTableAdapter.Fill(this.someDBDataSet.item);
}

private void noInspector_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    inspector_idComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Rather than adding a dummy item into the `ComboBox`, I added a (link) button to clear the `ComboBox`.

**Pros:**

1. The `ComboBox` clears.
2. The `tableAdapter` sets `item.inspector_id = NULL`

**Cons:**

1. Other form controls bound to `inspector` fields remain unchanged (as there is no "empty" `inspector` row to use).
2. No text is displayed in `inspector_idComboBox` when `SelectedItem` is null.  I'd prefer having something like `(none)` shown in the box.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to clear the `ComboBox` when selecting `(none)`:

```
private void inspector_idComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inspector_idComboBox.SelectedValue != null)
        if ((int)inspector_idComboBox.SelectedValue == -1)
            inspector_idComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

**Pros:**

1. The correct NULL value is saved to the DataSet and sent on to the database.
2. No external clear button is needed.

**Cons:**

1. Selecting `(none)` also clears the text.  I'd prefer for `(none)` to stay selected.