# Databinding combobox to null property

Tags: winforms, data-binding, combobox, null

I am working on a Windows Forms application against .NET 4.0 or 4.5.  The application uses several custom business objects, with a frequent pattern being that more complicated objects have simpler objects as properties. For example, a Location object is a two dimensional coordinate. But a Road has two properties, Start and End, of type Location. A Vehicle has a property FuelUsed that is of type Commodity. And so on.

In the user interface, users must edit instances of these types (e.g. Road, Vehicle). On my form, I typically define binding sources corresponding to the main type being edited, as well as types referenced by properties.  The data sources of these are generally of type `KeyedCollection`. For instance, the following code is in my form constructor on the road.

```
Friend WithEvents Me.bs_roads as System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource
Friend WithEvents Me.bs_locations as System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource

Me.bs_roads.DataMember = "Roads"
Me.bs_roads.DataSource = DataManager.Roads 

Me.bs_locations.DataMember = "Locations"
Me.bs_locations.DataSource = DataManager.Locations

Me.comboStart.DataSource = Me.bs_locations
Dim b As New Binding("SelectedItem", Me.bs_roads, "Start", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
Me.comboStart.DataBindings.Add(b)
```

This works fine as long as the Road.Start property is not `Nothing`. For instance, a newly constructed Road has a null Start property. But `comboStart` will show the **first** item in the `bs_locations` list.  If the user does not interact with the combo box, the property is not set, resulting in confusion and frustration. A further problem with this is that the user cannot easily set a property to a null value. I can provide a button to null the property, but again, the combo box does not keep up with the property.

My question: How can I create databound combo boxes that will correctly reflect null values, that will be simple to implement and maintain (that is, a minimum of custom code).

I have looked at probably a dozen SO questions. The closest one to my concern is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933969/combobox-databinding-nullvalue), which has no answers.  There is also [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481642/null-empty-item-in-bound-combobox) using SQL views to add a null the the combo boxes data source. I have had no success replicating it because my business objects are in KeyedCollections.

Comment: Why cannot use same default value for new instance of `Road`?

Comment: This is an option I have been able to do in some cases, such as when this property is of an enumeration type. In this example, I would have to have a default value for Road that connects two default or built in locations. As my objects get more complex, I rely on more and more defaults that are not meaningful to the user or really part of their data set. Thus my resistance.